# Will there be an official "What's new in TeX, version 3.141592653?" question to go along with the 2021 TeX tune-up?

Tags: discussion, questions

Back in 2014, a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154873/whats-new-in-tex-version-3-14159265) was posted, asking "What's new in TeX, version 3.14159265?". I know that the upcoming version of TeX will have at least one important bug fix, and I think it would be nice to have a corresponding, moderator-sanctioned question. I don't believe the earlier question was planned by the site, but as far as I am aware tex.se has been around to witness only the one update. I'd also suggest that a single, official "What's new" post be made for each new update henceforth.

(I hope I'm not out of line here. The 2014 question and [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154880/192444) were key factors in my getting interested in TeX. And there may be some interesting changes in this update.)

Comment: Two comments: 1) The next review won't be until 2028 (see  https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html), and 2) that's an interesting name for a new contributor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that such a question should be *mandatory*.*

Given that TeX aims to be as bug-free as possible, fixes are nowadays rather on the esoteric side, mostly about obscure corner cases, but who knows?

And surely, having a place where to look for “official” information, beside the usual TUGboat channel, would be handy.

<sup>* I don't think I'll ask it, though.</sup>